# minimum singular value for bigger matrix and small matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

Suppose $r\ll p$, and  $A_1,A_2,A_3 \in \mathbf{R}^{rxp}, rank(A_i)=r$. Define minimum singular value as $$\sigma_r(A_i)=\text{r-th singular value of} A_i$$ also define $\kappa_{\min }=\min \left\{\sigma_{r}\left(A_{1}\right), \sigma_{r}\left(A_{2}\right), \sigma_{r}\left(A_{3}\right)\right\}$

My question is following: suppose we combine the matrix $A_i$ by column to form a bigger matrix, i.e. $A=[A_1,A_2,A_3]\in \mathbf{R}^{rx3p}$, why the following hold?
$$\sigma_r(A)\asymp \kappa_{\min }$$

Comment: What does $\asymp$ mean?

Comment: Did you mean $\kappa_{\min} = \min\{\sigma_r(A_1), \sigma_r(A_2), \sigma_r(A_3)\}$?

Comment: Just to be clear, since $r < p$ we see that $\ker A_i$ is non trivial and so $\min_{\|u\|=1} \|A_i u\| = 0$. Presumably you had something else in mind?

Comment: $a \asymp b$ means that: exist universal constant $c_1,c_2>0$, such that $c_1b \leq a \leq c_2 b$. Yes, $\kappa_{\min }=\min \left\{\sigma_{r}\left(A_{1}\right), \sigma_{r}\left(A_{2}\right), \sigma_{r}\left(A_{3}\right)\right\}$.

Comment: perhaps my definition is not correct: so just change to r-th singular value